# Replacing source clips in a multicam sequence in Premiere

Tags: premiere, multi-camera

I've got a multi-camera sequence with approximately 1,000 painstakingly timed cuts between its 8 cameras. I just got new source material for those cameras (better renders of the same clips) and would like to replace the old renders with the new ones.

Is there any way to replace the videos *within* a multicam sequence? Or transfer/map the cuts to a new multi-camera sequence? Or any other creative solution?

Answer (score 2):

Save your project as a new version before you do this.

If the new higher quality files have the same file names as the old ones, you can re-link the media, so that the edit points to the new files instead of the old ones.

If the new files don't have the same frame rate as the old ones, none of your edits will match up.

If the resolution of the new files is different to the old ones, you may need to rescale all of your edits.  You can speed this process up by copying your Motion settings and using the [paste attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/premiere-pro/how-to/copy-paste-effects.html) command.

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/relinking-media.html